# How can i make single instance of all model classes in android?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-activity, singleton, dagger-2

what options do i have to make single instance of all the models classes in Android application?

I have added below one of the sample model class

```
public class User
{
    private String email;
    private String name;
    public String getEmail()           {  return this.email;    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {  this.email = email;   }
    public String getName()            {  return this.name;    }
    public void setName(String name)   {  this.name = name;   }
}
```

I want once data stored in Model Class, it can be retrieved in any activity class or fragment. Should i use singleton or any better approach is available ?

Will dagger2 work in this scenario ? is dagger2 alternative to creating singleton ?

Thanks

Comment: yes dagger will work in this scenario

Comment: Nilesh, are you sure ? can you have a look into this as this is what i am trying

Comment: You must create you object in application class

Comment: So you can access it all over the application in any activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184970/how-to-set-and-get-singleton-object-of-a-model-class-using-dagger2

Comment: I have added bounty on it ? can you explain what i am missing..

Comment: If i create an object in Application class, it will be global. Can not this be done using dagger2 without using Application Class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82592/discussion-between-muhammad-irfan-and-nilesh).